# How to set favicon of AWS Cognito hosted UI?

Tags: amazon-cognito, favicon

Is it possible to set a custom favicon to the AWS Cognito hosted UI?

I am aware that the Cognito web interface offers a number of CSS customization but favicon was not among them.

Comment: There is a [github thread open on this](https://github.com/amazon-archives/amazon-cognito-auth-js/issues/120). Right now, you can't do this.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think so. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=283090

Interestingly, when you do a re-direct from your site that has a favicon to your Cognito UI page for authentication then Chrome seems to carry your favicon over to the Cognito page and displays the icon in the tab. That only seems to work once you have gone through the authentication at least once. It does not work for other browsers. Maybe it is a bug in Chrome.